# Function shows `undefined` in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

My code:

```
    function geocodeAddress(address){
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode(
            {
                'address':address   
            },
            function(results,status){
                if(status===google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){ 
                    var resultsObj = results[0].geometry;
                    var resultsLocationObj = resultsObj['location'];
                    var lat = resultsLocationObj['k'];
                    var lon = resultsLocationObj['D'];
                    var coordinatesObj = {
                        address : address,
                        latitude : lat,
                        longitude : lon
                    };
                    return coordinatesObj;
                }
            }
        );
    }

$(document).ready(function(){
function initialize(){
        $('#save-address').click(
            function saveAddress(){
                var addressText = $('#address').val();
                console.log(geocodeAddress(addressText));
            }
        );
}
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

})
```

When the function runs, two things are printed to the console:

1. `undefined at line XXXX`, where `XXXX` is the line of the second
   `console.log()`.
2. The value for `coordinatesObj` (an object containing the address, latitude and longitude)

I want the second `console.log()` to show the value of `coordinatesObj`.

What do I do?

Comment: is `geocodeAddress` async?

Comment: ^ if it's Google's geocoder, it sure is.

Comment: @DanielA.White As adeneo says, it's Google's geocoder.

Comment: Do you actually have a dom element with the id of address? `$('#address').val()`

Comment: can you post more code? or make jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your markup, we can't say for sure what's happening, but from the code you've shown- I suspect that there is no HTMLInputElement element with "address".

```
$("#invalidId").val(); // returns `undefined`
```

Comment: There is. When my function  runs, I get the value of `$('#address').val()`

Comment: Probably going to need to provide more context then (plunker)